# next js router.push allow to open with new tabs but default behavior is open in the same tab

Tags: javascript, next.js

How to allow command+click open new tabs but default click is open with the same tab in Next js?
currently, I'm using router.push(url) and it's not allowed to open with new tabs (mouse right-click or command + click)
and I also tried window.open(url) but it always opens with new tabs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

Command + Click or Control + Click works only for link tags as anchor `<a href=""/>`.
If you want to listen on `click` event, when you should check ctrlKey in Event Object.

Example in VanillaJs, because it easy to adopt to any framework.

Because snippet works in sandbox, commandKey will fire error `Blocked opening 'https://stackoverflow.com/' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.`

```js
const url = 'https://stackoverflow.com';

document.getElementById('1').addEventListener('click', ev => {
  if(ev.ctrlKey){
    // Open new tab
    window.open(url);
  } else {
    // Open in this tab
    // uncoment next line
    // router.push(url);
    // Delete next line
    window.open(url, '_self');

  }
})
```

```html
<button id="1">SO</button>
```